# Angular 6 Unit Testing Dependant Promises

Tags: angular, typescript, http, testing, jasmine

I am new to Angular and I am currently writing unit tests for my application. I am really puzzled and can't seem to get any furthur with writing Unit Tests for my current task.
My component makes use of the following method:

```
async updateLevelModes(level: Level) {
    const updateModes: Promise<any>[] = [];
    for(let mode of level.Modes) {
      const updateMode = this.modeService.updateMode(mode);
      updateModes.push(updateMode);
    }
    await Promise.all(updateModes);
    const update = await this.LevelService.updateLevel(level);
    level.Id = update._id;
  }
```

It makes use of two services, the modeService and the levelService.

My LevelService.ts looks like this

```
async updateLevel(level: Level): Promise<void> {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('Name', level.Name);
    formdata.append('Description', level.Description);
    formdata.append('ImageFile', level.ImageFile);

    const resultLevel = await this.http.put<IStep>(this.postStepsUrl+'/'+step.Id, formdata)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
      .toPromise<IStep>();
    this.HandleStepResult(Level, resultLevel);
  }
```

How should I write a test for such a complicated method ? Kindly help

Comment: In the test of `updateLevelModes`, you could mock `modeService.updateMode` and `LevelService.updateLevel` so they return resolved promises, so you don't have to deal with all the logic in the service. Then you could assert that `level.Id` has been updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a "complicated" method :

- for each mode, update it
- update the level

From the provided code, you need two mocks and one expectation :

```
it('should update the level ID', () => {
  const newID = 5;
  spyOn(component['modeService'], 'updateMode').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  spyOn(component['modeService'], 'updateLevel').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({ id: newID }));

  component.updateLevelModes(component.level);

  expect(component.level.id).toEqual(newID);
});
```

Because you **unit test** your component, you should mock your dependencies. If you don't, expect your tests to be very random and difficult to implement.

This means that if you mock your service, you don't have to know what it does, you only have to know that it returns a new level with an ID.

This test, on the business side, is all you need to prevent side effects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply along with the code. I am still not able to bring it to work. On the second last line, I do not have access to the level property.

Comment: `component['level']` should bypass that

Comment: Well, from wherever your level comes then ! I though it was a member of your component, sorry